# UISplitViewController not calling delegate methods while pushing new detailView

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, delegates, uisplitviewcontroller

I setup a storyboard based on the Master-Detail Application, embed the detail view in a navigation controller, and add a new table view controller object which I will use as a second detail view controller.

I then push the new detail view controller with the following code (instead of a segue because I am pushing both a root view and a detail view controller at the same time.  Only the detail view code is shown).

```
// Push the detailView view controller:
NewClass *newViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"test"];

newViewController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
self.splitViewController.delegate                = newViewController;

[self.detailViewController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
```

This works perfectly, EXCEPT that the splitView delegate methods are never called before or after the push.  If I do this while in portrait mode, after it pushes the detailViewController, the button to drop down the masterView popover does not show up UNTIL I rotate to landscape mode and then back to portrait mode.

How can I cause the willHideViewController/willShowViewController split view controller delegate methods to be called or manually cause them to be called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So from what I found, it doesn't call the method because the orientation hasn't changed.

What you have to do is to pass the button from the presenting view controller since it's already tied to the popover like this:

```
if(self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem != nil) {
    newViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;
}

// Push the newViewController
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution.  I've had this exact problem and it has been driving me nuts for days.

Would you mind (if you remember - I understand it was over a year ago) showing me where you "found, it doesn't call the method because the orientation hasn't changed"?

Comment: At the bottom of the UISplitViewController class reference (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISplitViewControllerDelegate/splitViewController:willShowViewController:invalidatingBarButtonItem:) in the Discussion section of the two methods, it says "When the view controller rotates from a portrait to landscape orientation" (or vice-versa)....  When you push a new view controller, you aren't rotating.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm guessing I'm doing something that isn't recommended to run into this issue but it's not a showstopper so I'm going to sit on it for a while.