# UIBarButtonItem disappears when replacing DetailViewController, reappears after rotating

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, uisplitviewcontroller

After reading multiple threads relating to this I can only conclude that I must be setting my delegate at the wrong time, but I can't figure out where to assign the delegate to fix this.

I replace the detail view controller upon selection of a table row in the master like so:

```
AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
CustomerDetailViewController *newvc = [[CustomerDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomerDetailViewController" bundle:nil withCustomer:[custData objectForKey:@"name"]];            
[app.detailNavigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:newvc, nil]];
```

This sets the view controller.  In CustomerDetailViewController, I assign the delegate like so:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        app.splitViewController.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

What happens is if a table row is selected in portrait mode, I do not get the barbuttonitem appearing.  However, if I rotate to landscape and then back to portrait, the barbuttonitem does appear.

I figured setting my delegate in initWithNibName would fix this but apparently not.

Can anyone tell me where/when to assign the delegate??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found the solution - it appears to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871037/uisplitviewcontroller-not-calling-delegate-methods-while-pushing-new-detailview?rq=1) question.